# List of focusable widgets usable on Android TV

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im trying to make our app working on Android TV and i would like to know if there is a list of widgets somewhere which work better with Android TV app. (working focus, dpad button press, widgets navigation with dpad, etc)

I followed the very little doc I could find on the net like https://medium.com/@pcmushthaq/adding-android-tv-support-to-your-flutter-app-dcc5c1196231 but it doesnt help with all the focus issue.

I have some dynamic forms and the focus doesnt work between `TextFormField`, buttons, etc.

Also, on the tech side we trying to keep the android app as close as the mobile/tablet app, Is it ok or should i rewrite views with different widgets for the Android TV only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added `onEditionComplete: focousNode.requestFocous()` on password field, it does work in submit button but sometime it does not work with `.idk`